# How to repeatedly poll a URL in django?

Tags: python, django, request, push-notification, polling

I am building a push notification server in Django.

The first step that I want to build is to repeatedly poll a URL of my choosing every 1 minute or so.

I'm having trouble figuring out which tools I need for the job.

I gather that I need Django, one of the Python APNS packages, and what else?

Can I use the requests library (HTTP requests for humans library) to actually do the polling every minute?  Or would I need a cron job?  I'd appreciate sort of a gameplan.  I can't figure out how to call the same URL every minute and have it run in the background.

Thank you!

Comment: if you mean refreshin your whole page you must do It with js or you mean refreshin a single part of your page you must use django-dajaxice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is send a GET request to a URL, then cron + curl will work for you. Add the following line to your crontab ([how to](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=how+to+edit+crontab)):

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/curl --silent --compressed http://path.to/the/url
```

That will poll the URL once every minute, as long as your server is up.

---

If you want to integrate the polling with Django, check out [django-celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), a background task queue for Python and Django. First follow [Celery's Django installation guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), and then take a look at [this blog post](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2010/07/09/djangocelery-quickstart-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-using-cron-and-love-celery.html) talking about how to use celery as a cron replacement.

For your use case, you could replace the blog's example task with

```
import requests

from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour="*", minute="*", day_of_week="*"))
def test():
    response = requests.get('https://path.to/the/url/')
    process(response)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look at this.  I kept thinking cron cron cron but Celery looks like a more robust option.